# PHPMailer: Set mailed-by Message Header

Tags: php, phpmailer, email-headers

After sending an e-mail using PHPMailer to my Gmail account, after clicking 'show details,' to the right of 'mailed-by,' it says 'yourhostingaccount.com.' Here is a picture:

[image]

I've read you may change it using the fifth parameter of PHP mail(), although I'm not using that. Is there a way to change this using PHPMailer? Thanks!

Comment: Try `$mail->Hostname` property instead of `$mail->Host`. Accordingly to the [documentation](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=properties) this is the right field to use.

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work. It looks like it is a problem with FatCow, and I can't change what it says.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
$mail->Host = "domain.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that my domain and hosting provider, FatCow, uses NS1.YOURHOSTINGACCOUNT.COM and NS2.YOURHOSTINGACCOUNT.COM as their domain servers. This explains why it is happening, as I was connecting via SMTP to an e-mail address hosted by them. Unfortunately, I don't think I can change that and solve my problem... oh well.

Comment: Are you still experiencing this problem? I'm also hosted with FatCow and experiencing the same problem. I'm hoping there's a solution.